# JPA mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity-relationship

Hello I am new to JPA Spring boot and right now I am trying to make a connection between two tables into a third one. So I have a Doctor and Patient table with it's properties, where one Doctor can examine every patient and a patient can visit every doctor.But in one examination there can be no more than one patient and one doctor. For the doctors I want to keep the information of which patients they have examined, respectively for the patients, which doctors they were examined from. I would like to create a middle table called DoctorVisit where I have the id of the doctor who did the examination and the id of the patient with some more properties like date,medicines and etc. When I try to do this I am getting an error - "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: /.../Patient.examinedByDoctors". If I remove the @OneToMany connection in Patient the code compiles. I would be really happy if someone can explain me where is the mistake. Thank you in advance

BaseEntity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}
```

Doctor class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="doctor")
public class Doctor extends BaseEntity{

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy ="doctors")
    private Set<Specialty> specialties;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="doctor")
    private Set<Patient> GpOfPatients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor")
    private List<Patient> examinedPatients;
}
```

Patient class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
public class Patient extends BaseEntity{

    private String name;
    private String EGN;
    private boolean insurancesPaidInLastSixMonths;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="gp_id")
    private Doctor doctor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private List<Doctor> examinedByDoctors;

}
```

Specialty class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="specialty")
public class Specialty extends BaseEntity{

    private String specialtyName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="doctors_specialties",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="specialty_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="doctor_id"))
    private Set<Doctor> doctors;

}
```

DoctorVisit class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="doctorvisit")
public class DoctorVisit extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private Patient patient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="doctor_id")
    private Doctor doctor;

    private Date date;
    private String diagonosis;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "prescribedToPatients")
    private Set<Medicine> medicines;

    private int patientChart;

}
```

Medicine class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "medicine")
public class Medicine extends BaseEntity{

    private String name;
    private String manufacturer;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="prescribedMedicines_to_patients",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="medicine_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="patient_id"))
    private List<Patient> prescribedToPatients;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because the Doctor class does not have a *patient* field. However adding a Patient won't fit your use case, because a Doctor can have multiple Patients not just one. So you have to create a ManyToMany association between Patient and Doctor or use only the DoctorVisit to connect the two entities. I would apply the second option and use special queries to get who visited who with the *DISTINCT* keyword for example.

Comment: Well that was my main idea to connect them using the DoctorVisit table, but still cannot figure out how to avoid the error I am getting. Isn't the List<Patient> examinedPatients in Doctor class enough to make the One to many connection work for the DoctorVisit table?

Comment: Ah, okay, now I think I get what you would like to achive. At first I thought you would like to connect Patient with Doctor directly besides throught DoctorVisit. You have to change the Patient.examinedByDoctors' type form List<Doctor> to List<DoctorVisit> because you are referencing the wrong entity at the moment. And also in Doctor change examinedPatients to List<DoctorVisit> type. With these changes you will have an association throught DoctorVisit between Patient and Doctor.

Comment: Wow thank you dude you made my torments go away. I have never worked with Spring Boot before and it is really hard to understand what is going on. I am really grateful for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) I suggest reading this article about mappings: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/ (and any other blogposts from Vlad).

Comment: Will make sure to check it, thank you again mate.